# How do i get average based on the another column value Mysql

Tags: mysql

This is how table structure

```
Height     HeightType
 70         1
 71         1
 160        2
 120        2
 50         1
```

I want to get Average from this table height value. If Heighttype is 1 get height by multiplying its value by 2. if it's 2 get value as it is.
For example, the average would be(70*2)+(71*2)+160 +120+(50*2)/5
What is the MySQL query for this result

Answer (score 3):

```
select avg(case when HeightType = 1 then height * 2 else height end)
from your_table
```

Comment: Thanks It's working. How can we get this kind of answer?

Height     HeightType UnitType    Avg
 70         1                    'one'       181.440
 71         1                    'one'       181.440
 160        2                   'Two'      181.440
 120        2                   'Two'      181.440
 50         1                     'One'     181.440

Comment: If you have additional questions then ask it in a separate question and please explain in detail what your requirements are.  A comment is just to short to handle that#

Answer (score 1):

Please, try with below :

```
select avg(case when HeightType = 1 then (height * 2) else height end) as avg_height 
from table_name
```

Comment: how this differs from the other answer to this question?

Comment: Changes in more descriptive and name convention.